# all shortest paths between two points

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I have two points in a 10×10 array, and I want all the paths between these two points.
besides, I have restriction in my steps:
only [(Right then Up ), (Right then Down), (Left then Up), (Down then Left)] movement is allowed.
which algorithms can I use for this?

I tried with this code but didn't give me all paths

```
    void finding(int sW, int sH, int dW, int dH, String path,int strategy) {
        if(isOuted(sW, sH, dW, dH) || visited[dW][dH])return;
        visited[dW][dH] = true;
        if(strategy == 1){
        RD(sW, sH, dW, dH, path+"RU");
        RU(sW, sH, dW, dH, path+"RU");
        LU(sW, sH, dW, dH, path+"RU");
        DL(sW, sH, dW, dH, path+"RU");
        }else if strategy == 2 ...
    }
```

and in my methods, for exmaple RU (thats means Right then Up) i have:

```
private void RU(int sW, int sH, int dW, int dH, String path){

        if(isPath(++sW, sH, dW, dH)){
            System.out.println(path+"R");
            return;
        }
        if(isPath(sW, ++sH, dW, dH)){
            System.out.println(path+"RU");
            return;
        }
        finding(sW,sH,dW,dH,path,1);

    }
```

is this a good approach?!
I want an algorithm that more efficient and reliable.

Comment: First things first: Yeah, this is a good approach. 
But ... the datastructure "visited" to prohibit repeated visits is obviously global. This means all recursive steps will mark their steps and therefore a path which reaches a closed spot may be a new path but will stop its way and not be further recorded.
What can be done? Every path should mark its own way to prohibit circles.
What does this mean? You will get a big bunch of pathes and will need some memory. Is there an additional precept to get the shortest path (by cutting long trees you would free some memory)?

Comment: Isn't there always just one path because of the restrictions (or 2 if you can start from both points). E.g. (1,1) and (3,3) you can either start at (1,1) and go RRUU or you can start at (3,3) and go DDLL but this describes the same path. The exception is R+D+ and L+U+ which do not describe the same path.